# How to override database selector web page in odoo 11?

Tags: database, overriding, html, odoo

I want to beautify database selector web page in Odoo11. How can i do it? 
Do i have to create a new module? If yes, then in which database i have to install it?

I found the database selector file in ***/web/views/database_manage.html***

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest of using/adjusting one of the existing modules:
There is one module for this:
https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/web_extend_db_manager_layout/
You can possibly adjust it to your needs as it is open source. Remember to give some kudos to original authors.